# Does this plot indicate the data is normal distributed?

Tags: r, normality-assumption, quantiles, qq-plot

I use qqnorm to plot my data as the photo attached. Does this plot indicate the data is normal distributed?

[image]

Comment: This question may be better suited to the Cross-Validated stack exchange. However, I believe a Shapiro-Wilk test can give you an actual value for determining normality.

Comment: In a word, No, that doesn't look normally distributed. However, people often think they need normality when they don't at all.

Comment: It looks like a right-skewed distribution with discrete support

Comment: It would be fair to say this distribution is "approximately" Normal, for whatever such a vague statement might be worth.  If your concern is whether it has the principal characteristics of any random sample of a Normal distribution, the answer is definitely not: there are too many collections of tied values, as evidenced by the strings of adjacent horizontal points.

Comment: What's the data and the model? Often tied residuals are the result of fitting a model with categorical predictors only to count data. And in that case *approximately Normal* is the best that you can expect to get.

Comment: Furthermore, we can guess from the fact that the sample quantiles are all positive that this is very likely not a QQ plot of the residuals. Maybe the fitted values? If that's the case, that's the wrong QQ plot to be looking at because the normality assumption (in regression) is about the residuals not the *Y* values.

Answer (score 0):

On this plot, the sample doesn't look normally distributed at all. But for the normal distribution, there are formal statistical tests.

Comment: A few words of explanation would be welcome: exactly what features of this plot cause you to conclude the data do not look normally distributed?